# EF -> WCF -> JSON

Tags: javascript, wcf, json, entity-framework, serialization

I have a Windows Communication Foundation service which queries the Entity Framework and retrieves data in the form of Entity objects. I'd like to serialize these objects to JSON and send them back to the client to be interpreted in Javascript.

It seems this is tricky, according posts like these:

[http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/progr...tion-woes.aspx](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/program.x/archive/2009/03/18/wcf-json-serialization-woes.aspx)

At this time, what's the best way of doing this using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2? Data transfer objects are one way but is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services enables you to exchange entity data using the (JSON). For more information on this read this msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668804(VS.100).aspx